# tidesdk unresolved

Tags: tidesdk

Just installed TideSDK 1.3.1-beta.
When I try to launch "HelloWorld" example, I get these messages without knowing where to start to address the issue :

Unresolved: runtime 1.3.1-beta
Unresolved: app 1.3.1-beta
Unresolved: codec 1.3.1-beta
Unresolved: database 1.3.1-beta
Unresolved: filesystem 1.3.1-beta
Unresolved: media 1.3.1-beta
Unresolved: monkey 1.3.1-beta
Unresolved: network 1.3.1-beta
Unresolved: platform 1.3.1-beta
Unresolved: process 1.3.1-beta
Unresolved: ui 1.3.1-beta
Unresolved: worker 1.3.1-beta

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the SDK installation and getting started guide provided in [docs website](http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/guide/getting_started)
If you follow the steps described and install the SDK in correct location, you will have everything working.

Comment: I believe it is correctly installed under : ..library/Application Support/TideSDK/sdk/..., so there must be something else which is probably hardcoded. The App starts and tries to download stuff and gets : Installer App[2101:d07] Received 404 for http://api.appcelerator.net/p/v1/release-download?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem, then I found that after unzipping tideSDK, it gives us three folders, namely **sdk**, **modules** and **runtime**. All these three folders are supposed to be in ~/.tidesdk. But, I had only **sdk** inside the folder. So, I copied **runtime** and **modules** into ~/.tidesdk folder and then found HelloWorld App is now running.

I hope this one helps...Good Luck...